# Use bash script to extract certain type names and corresponding numbers

Tags: bash, sed, awk, extract

```
A: XXX (Done after 2 rounds)
A: YYY (Done after 1 rounds)
A: ZZZZ (Done after 4 rounds)
A: XXX (Done after 2 rounds)
A: ZZZZ (Done after 1 rounds)
A: YYY (Done after 2 rounds)
A: YYY (Done after 1 rounds)
```

For the above file, I want to extract certain names e.g. XXX, YYY, ZZZZ as well as the number of rounds for each name.

In the last, the result I expect is something like:

```
XXX 2 2
YYY 1 2 1
ZZZZ 4 1
```

I feel that I should use sed or awk, but not sure how to use them. Does anyone have good solutions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I feel that I should use sed or awk, but not sure how to use them". I recommend reading [sed & awk](http://tinyurl.com/SedAwkBook)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '{ names[$2] = names[$2] " " $5; } END { for (name in names) print name " " names[name] }' file
```

**Explanation:**

Each input line is passed to the command `names[$2] = names[$2] " " $5`, which creates an array called `names` whose indices are not numeric--they're the words that appear as the 2nd field in your input lines: `XXX`, `YYY`, and `ZZZZ`.  Their values accumulate the corresponding numbers in the 5th field of each line.

When the input file is exhausted, the `END` iterates through the index names, printing each name followed by its string of accumulated numbers.

Comment: v nice +1! However, you don't need " " in the print statement. Also, if piped into `sort`, you get the desired output, exactly.

Comment: It works. But I don't get it how the command `names[$2] = names[$2] " " $5` realizes accumulating number..

Comment: It's one of the wonders of awk.  Taking the first input line as an example, $1 = Classification:, $2 = "XXX", $3 = "(CLASSIFIED", $4 = "after", and $5 = "2".  So the command to awk becomes `names["XXX"] = names["XXX"] " " 2`.  Awk has "associative arrays," which means their indices can be non-numeric. The string "XXX" is used as as an index into the array called "names".  So the line sets the array _element_ to whatever it was before, followed by a space, followed by the number from the input line.  Does that help?

Comment: So for the first occurrence, what's the element value for `names["XXX"]`? since there is no initialization for `names["XXX"]`

Comment: Uninitialized variables in awk are empty.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html for more info.

Comment: @Adam Liss One more question, Can I further operate on these elements, like calculate sum of the numbers for each?

Comment: Absolutely, exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: @Adam Liss How should I do with them? I tried to write a function and then use the elements as the parameter, but it seems that the function doesn't work at all..

Comment: Time for a new question, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I like Perl data structures (hash of arrays) for something like this:

```
perl -lane '
        push @{$packets{$F[1]}}, $F[4]
    } 
    END {
        foreach $name (keys %packets) {print join(" ", $name, @{$packets{$name}})
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cut -d' ' -f2,5 file |
sort -sk1,1 |
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\(\S\+\).*\)\n\2/\1/;ta;P;D'
XXX 2 2
YYY 1 2 1
ZZZZ 4 1
```

Explanation:

- Extract fields 2 and 5 i.e. on the first line `XXX 2` using `cut -d' ' -f2,5 file`
- Sort by first field but preserve order `sort -sk1,1`
- Sed joins lines where the first field is the same and appends the second field. `sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\(\S\+\).*\)\n\2/\1/;ta;P;D'`

Ths sed command works as follows:

- Create a label `:a`
- Append a newline to the current line (pattern space PS) then the next line unless it is the last line. `$!N`
- Using the substitution command match the first field of the current line with the first field of the previous line and then remove it along with the preceeding newline. `s/^\(\(\S\+\).*\)\n\2/\1/`
- If the substitution was successful branch to the label. `ta`
- If the substitution was unsuccessful print the PS upto the first newline. `P`
- Delete the PS upto and including the first newline, then start a new cycle without refreshing the PS. `D`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not familiar with `sed`, could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @user1224398 I have edited my solution and provided an explanation.